# Duplicate Vector in Rolling Manner in R

Tags: r, vector, regression, rolling-computation

Say I want to run a regression whereby the data input for the DV should be taken in a rolling manner. To ease this process, I therefore first would like to "duplicate" that vector whereby I roll the observations accordingly. As example, see the data structure below.

```
# libraries #
library(dplyr)

# reproducible data # 
df1 <- tibble(ID = as.factor(rep(c(1, 2), each = 40)),
              YEAR = rep(rep(c(2001:2010), each = 4), 2),
              QTR = rep(c(1:4), 20),
              DV = rnorm(80))

df2 <- tibble(ID = as.factor(rep(c(1, 2), each = 120)),
              YEAR = rep(rep(c(2005:2010), each = 20), 2),
              IV = rnorm(240))
```

The reason the data is structured like this is because the data in df2 are residuals from earlier executed regressions that likewise used ["rolling" data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56021795/rolling-regression-in-r).

The aim is then to run a model whereby the observations in df1 are "rolled":

- regression 1: DV = rows 1-20 in df1, IV = rows 1-20 in df2
- regression 2: DV = rows 5-25 in df1, IV = rows 21-40 in df2
- regression 3: DV = rows 10-30 in df1, IV = rows 41-60 in df2
- and so on

The way I approached this problem is by trying to "duplicate" df1 in a rolling manner such that the regression is easier to execute.

For the moment I tried rolling it through the function `embed()` in the `base` package, but that becomes a mess very quickly as my real dataset is much larger. Would there be an elegent dplyr alternative?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could use

```
v1 <- c(1, seq(5, nrow(df1), by = 4))
v2 <- seq(20, nrow(df1), by = 4)
i1 <- seq_len(min(c(length(v1), length(v2))))
lst1 <- map2(v1[i1], v2[i1], ~ df1 %>% 
                           slice(.x:.y))
```

Similarly, do this with 'df2'

```
v11 <- seq(1, nrow(df2), by = 20)
v22 <- seq(20, nrow(df2), by = 20)
i2 <- seq_len(min(c(length(v11), length(v22))))
lst2 <- map2(v11[i2], v22[i2], ~ df2 %>% 
                           slice(.x:.y))
```

and then use `map2` to apply functions on corresponding elements of both `list`s

#### Update

As the OP mentioned about grouping by 'ID', one option is `group_split` by 'ID' and then use the same steps as above

```
df1 %>%
    group_split(ID) %>% 
    map(~ {
      v1 <- c(1, seq(5, nrow(.x), by = 4))
      v2 <- seq(20, nrow(.), by = 4)
      i1 <- seq_len(min(c(length(v1), length(v2))))
      map2(v1[i1], v2[i1], function(x, y) .x %>%
           slice(x:y))
   })
```

Comment: @Oscar That is fixed, with `i1` (check the 3rd line)